# Update reactiveValues in shiny R with multiple triggers

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to integrate esquisse into an app. At the moment I have an app that allows users to filter some data and I'd like to pass that data to esquisse. Esquisse takes reactiveValues as an input which are generally updated with observeEvent. However, I'm not sure how I can use observeEvent here as the data updates when there are changes to lots of different filters. Is there a way to update the values every time the data changes?

Example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(esquisse)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Use esquisse as a Shiny module"),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          mainPanel(
            selectInput(
              inputId = "am", 
              label = "am:", 
              choices = c(0,1)
            ),
            selectInput(
              inputId = "gear", 
              label = "gear:", 
              choices = c(3,4,5)
            ),
            selectInput(
              inputId = "carb", 
              label = "carb:", 
              choices = c(1,2,3,4,6,8)
            )
          )),
          tabPanel(
          title = "esquisse",
          esquisserUI(
            id = "esquisse", 
            header = FALSE, # dont display gadget title
            choose_data = FALSE # dont display button to change data
          )
        )
      )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_r <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(), name = "empty")

  data <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%
      filter(am == input$am,
             gear == input$gear,
             carb == input$carb
             )
  })

  data_r$data <- reactive({data()}) ### this doesn't work, so need something similar to this

  callModule(
    module = esquisserServer,
    id = "esquisse",
    data = data_r)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the example from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/esquisse/versions/0.2.3/topics/esquisserServer) (which I assume you did) carefully, you can probably see, that no `reactive(...)` parts are used. To fix your server part, use (as in the example) a combination of `reactiveValue` and `observeEvent`.

The `reactiveValue` is used, to initialize a default variable called `data_r`. To update the variable, the `observeEvent` observes the input parameters `am`, `gear` or `carb` and change the `data_r` when ever one of the input paramter changes.

Your server function can look like:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # initialize data_r
  data_r <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(), name = "empty")

  # reactive filter for data_r on events am, gear and carb
  observeEvent(
    {input$am
     input$gear
     input$carb
     1}, # last object not NULL needed here!
    {am_filter <- input$am
     gear_filter <-  input$gear
     carb_filter <- input$carb

     data_r$data <- iris %>% 
       filter(Sepal.Length == am_filter, 
              Sepal.Width == gear_filter, 
              Petal.Length == carb_filter)}
  )

  callModule(module = esquisserServer, id = "esquisse", data = data_r)
}
```

Mention that the `iris` data set did not have columns `am`, `gear` or `carb`! The propose of the above server example, is to run the server function within you example.